# Collapsing categorical data easily for regression in R

Tags: r, logistic, categorical-encoding

I have read an [article](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/courses/ling289/logistic.pdf) from Christopher Manning, and saw an interesting code for collapsing categorical variable in an logistic regression model:

```
glm(ced.del ~ cat + follows + I(class == 1), family=binomial("logit"))
```

Does the `I(class == 1)` means that the `class` variable has been recoded into either it is `1` or it is not `1`?

After that, I am thinking of modifying it a bit:

```
glm(ced.del ~ cat + follows + I(class %in% C(1,2)), family=binomial("logit"))
```

I am planning to merge the variable `class` from `c(1,2,3,4)` into two groups, one group contains `c(1,2)`, another group contains `c(3,4)`, can the code above give me the result I want?

Comment: why haven't you tried it yourself? This of course works. There is a typo in your code, capital C instead of c.

Comment: I tried already, but since I have no idea of how to counter-check the result, so I wonder if anyone can enlighten me here, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This shows what the first is doing:

```
> class <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
> class == 1
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> as.numeric(class == 1)
 [1] 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
> ## or better,
> factor(as.numeric(class == 1))
 [1] 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
Levels: 0 1
```

`class == 1` is creating an indicator variable as you surmise. The `I(....)` bit is due to us having to insulate certain operations from R's formula parsing code.

Similarly, `class %in% c(1,2)` is doing the same thing but matching on `1` *or* `2`:

```
> class %in% c(1,2)
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> as.numeric(class %in% c(1,2))
 [1] 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
> ## etc
```

and it works within the modelling calls:

```
> set.seed(1)
> dat <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(100), X1 = rnorm(100), 
+                   class = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE))
> mod <- lm(Y ~ X1 + I(class %in% c(1,4)), data = dat)
> coef(mod)
              (Intercept)                        X1 I(class %in% c(1, 4))TRUE 
                  0.138287085              -0.003827624              -0.072059592
```

but I think it is neater if you create a new variable for the class compression you want and use that directly in your model:

```
> dat <- within(dat, class2 <- factor(class %in% c(1, 4),
+                                     levels = c(FALSE,TRUE)))
> mod2 <- lm(Y ~ X1 + class2, data = dat)
> coef(mod2)
 (Intercept)           X1   class2TRUE 
 0.138287085 -0.003827624 -0.072059592
```